# Count how many permutations of list possible as long as it 'fits' into another list

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to find how many arrangements of a list are possible with each arrangement 'fitting' into another list (i.e. all elements of the arrangement have to be less than or equal to the corresponding element). For example, the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` has to fit in the list `[2, 4, 3, 4]`.

There are 8 possible arrangements in this case:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 4, 3, 1]
```

Because 3 and 4 cannot fit into the first slot of the list, all arrangements that start with 3 or 4 are cut out. Additionally, 4 cannot fit into the third slot, so any remaining arrangements with 4 in the third slot are removed.

This is my current code trying to brute-force the problem:

```
from itertools import permutations  

x = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
box = [2, 4, 3, 4] # this is the list we need to fit our arrangements into

counter = 0

for permutation in permutations(x):
  foo = True
  for i in range(len(permutation)):
    if permutation[i] > box[i]:
      foo = False
      break
  if foo:
    counter += 1
print(counter)
```

It works, but because I'm generating all the possible permutations of the first list, it's very slow, but I just can't find an algorithm for it. I realize that it's a basically a math problem, but I'm bad at math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the `x` in reverse, you can try to find all the spots each element can fit in the box one at a time.

In your example:

- 4 has 2 spots it can go
- 3 has 3 spots, but you have to account for already placing the "4",
  so you have 3 - 1 = 2 available
- 2 has 4 spots, but you have to account for already placing two things
  (the "4" and "3"), so you have 4 - 2 = 2 available
- 1 has 4 spots, but you have already placed 3... so 4 - 3 = 1

The product 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 is 8.

Here's one way you can do that:

```
import numpy as np
counter = 1
for i, val in enumerate(reversed(sorted(x))):
    counter *= ( (val <= np.array(box)).sum() - i)
print(counter)
```

...or without numpy (and faster, actually):

```
for i, val in enumerate(reversed(sorted(x))):
    counter *= ( sum( ( val <= boxval for boxval in box)) - i)
```

Comment: can you do this without the numpy library?

Comment: Added.  I have pandas/numpy on the brain a lot, so just default to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented a bit with timings and here's what I found:

#### Your original code

```
for permutation in permutations(x):
    foo = True
    for i in range(len(permutation)):
        if permutation[i] > box[i]:
            foo = False
            break
    if foo:
        counter += 1
```

Took about 13569 ns per run

#### Filtering the permutation

```
for i in range(100):
    res = len(list(filter(lambda perm: all([perm[i] <= box[i] for i in range(len(box))]), permutations(x))))
```

Took slightly longer at 16717 ns

#### Rick M

```
counter = 1
for i, val in enumerate(reversed(sorted(x))):
    counter *= ((val <= np.array(box)).sum() - i)
```

Took even longer at 20146 ns

#### Recursive Listcomprehension

```
def findPossiblities(possibleValues, box):
    return not box or sum([findPossiblities([rem for rem in possibleValues if rem != val], box[1:]) for val in [val for val in possibleValues if val <= box[0]]])
findPossiblities(x, box)
```

Even longer at 27052 ns.

As a conclusion, using itertools and filtering is probably the best option

Comment: It's true if you measure this on his example with only 4 elements the numpy version isn't faster, though the 2nd one in my post still beats the original loop by a factor of 3x.

My assumption was that they wanted longer lists, but you're correct that if their problem was that they needed to do this smaller-list operation a lot of times then optimizing it as-is would help. The 2nd version I posted does help with that.

If you make the lists have 10 elements, my 2nd version is 8.75 microsec vs 1.17 *sec* for a random example. At 200 elements, it's ~3 ms vs. longer than I'm willing to wait.

Comment: I think it would be more interesting to analyze time complexity rather than the average time taken for my initial example. e.g. my solution has `O(n!)` complexity, so it's the worst out of all of them.